# Node identification in ethereum network

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes

I have set up a private network. Is there a way to be notified when node joins the network? 
I connect all the nodes using a bootnode. I know that I can check all the nodes that are peers using admin.peers but is there a way to be notified when any node joins.